# Optimizing membership check

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have some problems in checking whether some data is inside two large data sets.

Say I have the data for which I want to check membership in the form of a list of 9 digits: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Now I have two other datasets containing some random variation of this data: `[1,2,3,6,7,0,8,4,5]`, `[8,0,3,1,7,2,3,4,5]` etc... 
These datasets `dataset1` and `dataset2` are quite large, containing up to 300.000 of these kind of values.

Right now I am storing my data as lists, and the datasets as lists containing these lists. Using the following code, the membership operation takes way too long.

```
# Solution 1, too slow
if data not in (dataset1 + dataset2):
    # do something

# Solution 2, also too slow
if data not in dataset1:
    if data not in dataset2:
        # do something
```

In what way can I optimize this test? I just chose to store the data in lists, but would another datastructure be more efficient? I could also compare strings (like `'012345678'`) for instance.

Comment: Could you store the data as a dict and then use try/except to test?

Comment: Try using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Sets are fast for containment checks.

Comment: Sets are good at containment testing, but they require all the items in them to be unique. You'll also lose the ordering of the original data (if that matters).

Comment: The [TimeComplexity wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) is a useful thing to keep handy.

Comment: @khelwood I beleive can't store lists in sets, should I maybe represent my data as strings, or should I change to something else, tuples for example?

Comment: @ｒｉｃｋｅｒｔ You would have a `set` of ints, not a `set` of lists